# How to run Terraform without specify provider?

Tags: terraform, openstack, terraform-provider-openstack

I was wondering if it is possible to run `terraform` without specifying the `provider` block, and instead rely purely on environmental variables?

Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
export TF_VAR_user_domain_name="foo"
export TF_VAR_tenant_id="faa"
export TF_VAR_tenant_name="fii"
export TF_VAR_user_name="name"
export TF_VAR_region="region"
export TF_VAR_auth_url="url"
```

Instead of :

```
provider "openstack" {
  user_name   = "admin"
  tenant_name = "admin"
  password    = "pwd"
  auth_url    = "url"
  region      = "RegionOne"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to assign a provider name to a tf_env var. Because of this, Terraform would have no way of knowing what resources to expose to you without a provider block.

[From TF Docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/):

> A provider is responsible for understanding API interactions and exposing resources.

What are you trying to accomplish? Is there some underlying need? Or was this just an experiment?